# Set of points with minimal fibre-dimension is open

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to see why the following statement is true:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be irreducible quasiprojective varieties with $\dim X = n$ and $\dim Y = m$. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a regular surjective map. Then the set $\tilde Y :=\{y \in Y \ | \ \dim f^{-1}(y) = n-m \}$ is non-empty and open in $Y$.

The idea is to use the theorem on dimension of fibres:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be regular map between irreducible quasiprojective varieties. Suppose that $f$ is surjective, and that $\dim X =n$ and $\dim Y = m$. Then $m \leq n$ and (i) $\dim F \geq n-m$ for any $y \in Y$ and for any component $F$ of the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$; (ii) there exists a nonempty open subset $U \subseteq Y$ such that $\dim f^{-1}(y) = n -m$ for $y \in U$.

By $(ii)$ of the theorem it follows that $\tilde Y$ contains a non-empty open set. However I don't see, why $Y \setminus \tilde Y$ should be closed.

Is the above statement correct?

Comment: If $f$ is proper and $\dim f^{-1}(y)\ge n-m$, this follows from upper semi-continuity of fiber dimensions.